# Amazon rds instance asking for IP permission all IPs already authorized?

Tags: amazon-rds

learning amazon aws these days,i've encountered a problem.To test NerdDinner app in amazon ec2,i have set up an ec2 instance with a security group that accepts connections to SQL Server  port 1433,and i have created an rds instance and i added all IPs +EC 2 security group(port 1433)

using vs 2010 aws toolkit, when i try to create a database,the rds instance is still asking for my IP to be added to the db security group.See the pics.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The strange thing is that when i connect from another wifi(home wifi),i can access to the db instance.Now i can't access it from company wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Is port 1433 open at your office?  You might want to verify that.